# Efficient way to get part of a string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I have to parse a string to obtain a specific value in it.

Here's an example of a string I need to parse: `"@MSG 12,9: NINJUTSU"`

Here I need to obtain the `12` value. The order of the value will not change, meaning that I will always aim the first number in the string; however the length of the string (`12`, `9`, `58`) is variable (but never negative) and the message (`NINJUTSU`) is also changing.

So far I proceed like this:

```
Dim tempErrorList As List(Of String) = errorMsg.Split(New Char() {":"}).ToList()

Dim listErr As List(Of String) = tempErrorList(0).Split(New Char() {","}).ToList()

Dim errCode As List(Of String) = listErr(0).Split(New Char() {" "}).ToList()
```

However I don't like it because of the 3 splits needed to obtain the values. I do not know how I could do it in one shot or fewer operations?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Regex.

Comment: Yeah, well there was this Regex answer that provided info, but I don't know why, the user deleted his post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the deleted answer, you could use `String.Split` like so:  `errorMsg.Split(" ,:".ToCharArray())`, which does what you're doing above but with one function call.

`errorMsg.Split(" ,:".ToCharArray())(1)` would give you the `"12"` you need.

Alternatively, you can use combinations of `String.SubString()` with `String.IndexOf()`, but the logic can become unwieldy and opaque.  [String.Split Alternatives (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx#Alternatives) gives more details on this approach.